# Updating many records via "Linq to entities" and not "Linq to objects"

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

Is it possible to update many records via *Linq To Entities* as opposed to *Linq To Objects*?

The following is done **in memory**, because of the "ToList()"

```
foreach (Person person in dbContext.Persons.Where(...).ToList())
{
    person.Name = person.Name.Trim();
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

The same query for selecting people in Linq To Entities (not in memory) would be just `dbContext.Persons.Where(...)`, without ToList(), but then how do I update things there? There is no thing such as `from person in db.Persons.Where(...) update blah`

If this is not possible, am I forced to do this massive update via direct SQL?

Answer (score 0):

erm,

```
foreach (Person person in dbContext.Persons.Where(...))
{
    person.Name = person.Name.Trim();
}

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Doesn't that throw an error when the update involves relationships?

Comment: @sports, do you have an association based on `Name`?

Comment: no. I always fail on this.. try to use a simplified example in my stackoverflow's thread and then the problem is just not present with the example. But either way, without using .ToList() i've had problems in the past. Im searching for the literal error to paste it here.

Comment: @sport essentially, you need to ensure you have satisfied the databases constraints before you call `SaveChanges`, otherwise you will violate the databases integrity and your transaction will not commit.

Comment: It will still perform the update in memory and then send proper `UPDATE` sql queries when `SaveChanges` is called.